# Estimating $\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} \cos (n^2x) \right)^4\ dx$ for large $N$

Tags: calculus, analysis, integral-inequality

In a paper I am reading, it is claimed without proof that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ and $N > N_0(\varepsilon)$
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} \cos (n^2x) \right)^4\ dx < N^{2 + \varepsilon}
$$
I do not quite see how this follows. The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality shows that
$$
\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} \cos (n^2x) \right)^4 \le N^2\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} \cos^2(n^2x) \right)^2 \le N^3\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} \cos^4(n^2x) \right)
$$
and hence
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} \cos (n^2x) \right)^4\ dx \le N^3\int_0^{2\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{N} \cos^4(n^2x) = \frac{3}{4}\pi N^4,
$$
but this is evidently not good enough. Any help proving the claim is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but if we can somehow show that $\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left[\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\cos(n^2 x)\right)^4 dx\right]}{\ln(N)}=2$, the claim follows.

Comment: Write $cosn^2x$ as $\frac{e^{n^2}x - e^{-n^2}x}{2i}$. Then the problem becomes about the number of solution of $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = 0$ where $a,b,c,d$ are in ${-{N}^2,...,0,...,{N}^2}$.

Comment: Could you give a link for the paper ?

Comment: @Salcio I'd rather say "_$\pm a^2\pm b^2\pm c^2\pm d^2=0$ with $a,b,c,d\in[1..N]$_", which essentially boils down to $a^2=b^2+c^2+d^2$ and $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$, which both have more or less clear geometric meaning. Then again, maybe that's where the problem really originates, and the solution lies elsewhere.